# Convert byte string to string in python

Tags: python

I'm using PyCrypto, and python 2.7.3.  I'm attempting to prepend a regular string to the hash to create a chained hash, but to keep formats consistent, I need the string s in the 'printed' form instead of the binary form.  Is there any way to convert the binary string into a manipulable "normal" string?

```
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256
h = SHA256.new()
s = h.digest() #return binary "non-printable" digest

s
>>>"\xe3\xb0\xc4B\x98\xfc\x1c\x14\x9a\xfb\xf4\xc8\x99o\xb9$'\xaeA\xe4d\x9b\x93L\xa4\x95\x99\x1bxR\xb8U"
print(s)
>>> ã°ÄB˜üšûôÈ™o¹$'®Aäd›“L¤•™xR¸U
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you see when entering `s` in the interactive interpreter is the *representation* of the string.  You shouldn't be concerned about what this looks like – the actual string contents is what gets printed when you use print.  There is no way to "convert" the string to what is printed when using `print` since the string already *has* that contents.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `.hexdigest()` instead. You will get a string representation as hex digits.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if i got you right, but if you mean a hex-representation you may look into the `binascii`-module of the std-lib:

```
from binascii import b2a_hex #bin to ascii: hex-format
print b2a_hex(s)
'e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855'
```

if you just want to prepend a string to s, it's like Sven Marnach said, don't bother what is
printed, just append s to your prefix, like:

```
prefix = 'username:'
combined_string = prefix + s
```